# Simple ArrayList Autocomplete does not display

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I am trying to get an autocomplete list to pop up, using this [link as a guide.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm)

Though, when I start typing "Re" for Red, nothing shows up.

*What am I doing wrong?*

**In my activity**

```
ArrayList<String> arrayColors = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayColors.add("Red");
arrayColors.add("Orange");
arrayColors.add("Yellow");
arrayColors.add("Green");
arrayColors.add("Blue");
arrayColors.add("Indigo");
arrayColors.add("Violet");

AutoCompleteTextView colorField = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.editColor);
colorField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});

ArrayAdapter<String> colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayColors);
colorField.setAdapter(colorAdapter);
colorField.setThreshold(1);
```

**Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mycompahy.myapp.DetailsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_details">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    //OTHER CONTROLS

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:maxLines="1" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The error message I get:

> W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
>                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: collection == null
>                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:94)
>                                                                         at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:456)
>                                                                         at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after I tried your code. You have to set some width to `AutoCompleteTextView` and then you will be able to see the pop up. For example set the width to `match_parent`.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/editColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Are you saying that layout_width should me match_parent, not wrap content?

Comment: Yes, that is what I say

Comment: You didn't change wrap_content to match_parent in AutoCompleteTextView take a look my answer again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107349/discussion-between-ivan-ivanov-and-firemarble).